# Когда будет уничтожен фрейм?

Tags: c#

Читал я тему про перегрузку операторов и видел, что, собственно, из этого метода возвращается ссылка на новый объект, но ведь есть такая вещь - время жизни переменной, и её время жизни ограничено временем выполнения метода, и как только метод закончит свою работу, из стека будет выпилен фрейм стека вместе со всеми локальными переменными. И каким тогда образом переменная та вернётся?

Вот пример кода, чтобы хоть как-то конкретизировать:

```
class Counter
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public static Counter operator +(Counter c1, Counter c2)
    {
        return new Counter { Value = c1.Value + c2.Value };
    }
    public static bool operator >(Counter c1, Counter c2)
    {
        return c1.Value > c2.Value;
    }
    public static bool operator <(Counter c1, Counter c2)
    {
        return c1.Value < c2.Value;
    }
}
```

Теперь я бы хотел уточнить: когда, собственно, фрейм этого самого операторного метода будет "уничтожен", с момента когда мы вернём значение или же когда мы попадём на закрывающую скобку?

Comment: Вас смущает значение, возвращаемое из `operator +`, или из остальных тоже?

Comment: @Igor меня смущает появление идиотских вопрос во время прочтение книги, вопросов которы ранее не возникало. Я прекрасно понимаю что из метода вернётся ссылка(new возвращает ссылку на созданный объект), я задаюсь идиотским вопросом как это дело происходит ведь даже если бы мы создали локальную переменную того класса counter и впихнули её в return как бы она вернулась если всё что есть в методе возвращается уничтожается вместе с его фреймом в момент окончания выполнения метода

Comment: под результат функции отводится особое место

Comment: @Igor я не совсем уверен уместно ли это, но хотел бы спросить возможно ли связаться с вами каким-нибудь скайпом или ещё чем угодно?

Comment: Если переменная которая будет объявлена локально внутри фрейма метода не будет использоваться кроме как внутри метода, то объект будет создан на стеке метода и будет `утилизирован` сборщиком мусора при выходе из метода. Если вы возвращаете ссылку на локальный объект, то он будет помещен в кучу `сборщика мусора`. Таким образом вы можете вернуть на него ссылку. Если вы объявите структуру с меткой `ref` и попробуете вернуть на такую структуру ссылку, то вы получите ошибку времени компиляции т.к. такие структуры хранятся только и только в стеке методов. Надеюсь немного прояснил ваш разум.

Comment: *будет `утилизирован` сборщиком мусора при выходе из метода.* А можно поподробней? Если Вы написали `var v = new SomeClass();` то ссылка на объект, сохранённая в переменной `v`, уже была использована в другом методе (конструкторе класса `SomeClass`), который мог эту ссылку сохранить или передать в другой метод. Поэтому нет никаких гарантий, что `v` единственная ссылка на объект. Таким образом сборщик мусор не имеет права утилизировать объект, как только переменная `v` вышла из области видимости.

Comment: Кажется я кое-что нащупал, и понял как спросить то что меня интерисуе.
Значится так когда мы вызываем метод то ему собственно передаётся управление и он попадает в стек вызовов функций, и хотелось бы узнать когда именно считается что метод отработал в момент когда мы выполнили инструкцию return или же когда попали на закрывающую скобку и только тогда фрейм этого метода в котором все его локальные переменные уничтожается?

Comment: @Mark *попали на закрывающую скобку* Что Вы называете закрывающей скобкой? `}` в конце тела метода? Согласно правилам C# метод, который должен вернуть значение, не может дойти до конца своего тела. Компилятор сообщит об ошибке, если посчитает, что конец тела такого метода достижим.

Comment: @PetSerAl закрывающая фигурная скобка

Comment: Ранее читая главу допустим с методами меня как-то особо не волновало как там что происходит, но напоровшись на информацию о стеке вызовов и собственно о том что есть такая штука как фрейм метода в котором хранятся локальные переменные(и не только) я узнал что когда метод отрабатывает его фрейм со всем что внутри уничтожается то бишь если где-то в методе мы объявилу переменную того класса сounter и запихнули сумму полей двух аргументов то собственно когда метод отработает из стека будет убрана ссылка вместе с фреймом метода и как же она вернётся то если на момент окончания она уже будет убита?

Comment: Читайте комментарий @Igor: *под результат функции отводится особое место*. Результат функции не умирает вместе с фреймом стека.

Comment: мне кажется вы немного путаете понятия "переменная" и "значение переменной". Все локальные переменные будут уничтожены по завершению выполнения метода. А вот их значения, не важно ссылка на объект в куче или данные структуры, могут быть переданы в вызывающий контекст разными способами. Например значение, возвращаемое через return окажется на вершине стека после завершения метода. Есть и другие варианты.

Comment: @Igor это особое место имеет название? Мне иногда легче что-то осознать если увидеть это что-то,сейчас сижу копаюсь и ищу информацию поэтому делу и мне кажется что я скоро полезу до ассемблерных команд и сойду с ума(Похожая ситуация у меня было с приколом про передачу параметров в методы сейчас не об этом)

Comment: хммм, всё ещё есть вопросец, собственно происходит когда мы по ходу выполнения метода натыкаемся на инструкцию return мы получается пишем то что хотим вернуть в то как мне сказали особое место значение что хотим вернуть и затем идём дальше и натыкаемся на фигурную скобку и собственно это является сигналом для уничтожения фрейма стека?

Comment: @rdorn то значение о котором вы говорите что окажется на вершине стека, разве возвращаемое значение не "вставляется" туда где был вызван метод, или есть ещё какие-то забавные штуки о которых я ни сном ни духом и пытаюсь въехать не понимая что я за что-то зацепился и потому никак не могу?

Comment: Посмотрите в ответе, описание конечно обобщенное, но для понимая, думаю, будет достаточно. Может кто напишет более подробно про конкретную реализацию в CLR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ладно, попробую, если что - сильно не бить, давненько не приходилось поднимать подобные темы из памяти, что-то мог и забыть.

Для начала основной вопрос:

> когда, собственно, фрейм этого самого операторного метода будет "уничтожен", с момента когда мы вернём значение или же когда мы попадём на закрывающую скобку?

Фигурные скобки (C, С++, C# и им подобные), begin-end и аналогичные конструкции других языков - это всего лишь условность, подсказка компилятору, где блок кода начинается и где заканчивается. Т.е. для исполняемого кода их не существует. Завершение работы метода происходит при выполнении команды `return` (в IL-коде `ret`, в ASM-е тоже есть аналогичная команда. Работать и интерпретироваться они, разумеется, могут и будут по-своему).

Стоит немного оговориться, что в режиме отладки иногда (в C# можно) действительно можно попасть как на открывающий, так и на закрывающий терм, однако это также условность, но уже отладчика. И хотя в некоторых случаях для реализации подобного поведения отладчика используют специальные "пустые" низкоуровневые операции, на которых можно остановиться во время выполнения без имитации, а по-настоящему, это фактически ничего не меняет - условность остается условностью.

Ну и попробую помочь немного выпутаться из "дебрей". Для начала несколько базовых понятий, которые нужно четко различать и, крайне желательно, использовать соответствующие термины по назначению.

**Переменная** - изменяемая область памяти, размер которой определяется исходя из типа хранимых в ней данных. В разных языках и исполняемых средах может располагаться как в статической(фиксированный адрес), так и в динамической(стек) памяти.

**Значение переменной** - непосредственно данные. Данные могут храниться в переменной непосредственно (так называемые типы-значения) или в отдельном сегменте памяти - куче. В последнем случае в переменной будет храниться значение ссылки (или указателя, если говорить не только про C#), по которой к ним можно обратиться.

Большинство (могу ошибаться) современных ЯП используют, так называемую, стековую модель работы с памятью в исполняемом коде. Фактически это означает, что все локальные переменные в исполняемом коде размещаются на стэке. Передача параметров подпрограммам и возврат результата в такой модели также происходит через стэк. При этом команды исполняемого кода и данные, с которыми он работает, фактически, находятся в отдельных блоках памяти и не пересекаются.

Что происходит при вызове подпрограммы в стековой модели:

1. Запоминается текущее положение вершины стека.
2. На вершину кладутся входные параметры.
3. Управление передается подпрограмме.
4. Выполнение кода подпрограммы до одной из команд return.
5. Восстановление сохраненного состояния вершины стека.
6. Запись в стек результата (если необходимо)
7. Возврат управления вызвавшему коду.

Практически сразу видно одно из главных преимуществ подобного подхода - простейшая очистка памяти, занимаемой локальными переменными, после завершения подпрограммы. Можно сказать очистка памяти выполняется одной командой процессора (см. пункт 5).

Данное описание, разумеется очень обобщенное. Реализации могут отличаться, но общая схема все равно сохраняется, так как имеет ряд преимуществ, которые перекрывают имеющиеся недостатки.

Comment: Итак, после полуночных изысканий я выяснил следующее, вот то самое возвращаемое значение помещается в регистр процессора eax(в большинстве случаев из того что я читал зависит от архитектуры) и теперь хотелось бы узнать может кто-то знает каким образом из этого регистра возвращённое значение попадает на место вызова метода и если знаете, то умоляю нарисуйте или быть может знаете ресурс где есть какая-нибудь иллюстрация, ибо из тех примеров что я видел рисуют просто стек и кучу,а тут я ещё выяснил что возвращаемое значение вначале в регистр процессора и только потом на место вызова

Comment: @Mark ну так результат любой операции попадает сначала в один из регистров процессора. Так что тут ни какого противоречия. Вообще вы зря сейчас смешиваете в кучу низкоуровневую и высокоуровневую модели выполнения. Их нужно изучать по отдельности, а потом картинка сама сложится. Можете попробовать окунуться в ассемблер, ближе к процессору ничего нет, но архитектура intel не слишком дружелюбна, так что если надумаете - морально готовьтесь "страдать" =)

Comment: короче я понял, в вузе берут преподают что-то относительно высокоуровневое и надеются что человек не станет задавать вопросов и собственно пока учился в универе проблем таких то и не было, а как понял что мало что умею и решил копаться сам(да-да давайте скажите мол так ты же поступил и получил значит знал на что идёшь и нужно было работать) и теперь как я понял лучше уже просто уяснить что возвращаемое значение не уничтожается вместе со стеком, а просто помещается в тот регистр процессора и затем из него попадает на место вызова метода

Comment: И кстати кто-то сказал мол неучей полно в профессии, а тут попался один кто хочет разобраться и это плохо, что он хочет перестать мучиться вопросом, но из-за таких вот идиотских вопросов я просидел до 3 ночи пока не нашёл про эти регистры и на самом деле гораздо лучше не издеваться над собой в поисках ответов на дурные вопросы попутно останавливая изучение хотя тут больше повторение изученного материал это есть уже ненужный маразм и пустая трата времени

Comment: Порой кажется было бы проще застрелиться или иметь возможность стирать из памяти дурные вопросы дабы потом не сидеть до 3 ночи.
P.S спасибо за участие и попытки дать ответ господа

Comment: @Mark что преподают в вузе - зависит от вуза. Стреляться не надо, просто не смешивайте все в кучу - сами же потом запутаетесь и перестанете понимать что откуда растет. Изучайте постепенно и не важно от высокого уровня к низкому или наоборот.

Comment: @Mark ну и конечно однозначного ответа на все ваши почему и как не будет, к сожалению. Все очень сильно зависит от конкретных реализаций компиляторов, оптимизаторов, исполняющих сред (при их наличии), архитектуры процессоров. Везде есть своя специфика, поэтому имеет смысл понимать общие принципы, а остальное только в случае реальной серьезной работы в с конкретными продуктами.

Comment: всё проблема для меня была в том что прочитав про фрейм метода который удаляется по окончанию работы метода со всем содержимым включая локальные переменные я считал что теряется значение, а оно оказывается помещается в регистр процессора из которого затем попадает на место вызова этого метода и вот этого я не знал и не понимал и меня это выводило из себя

Comment: и ещё хотел спросить выполнение инструкции return означает конец выполнения метода и является сигналом к удалению его фрейма из стека вызова?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92398/discussion-between-rdorn-and-mark).